# regarding passing the wrong object

Tags: python, flask, regression

I was building a project where I need to take a form text from html and give it to predict_proba() function of the model file imported. I am using logistic regression. But every time I pass the input string X to the function it gives me that string is not a correct object type to be passed. the same happens with lists.

Comment: Hi @dhrruv, the question as it stands is way too broad. What is `predict_proba()`? What is "the model file"? Why do you expect a string to work when calling that function? What errors are being raised? Please show us some of your code and attempts, otherwise we can't do the guesswork for you.

Comment: Here is predict_proba definition: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Answer (score 0):

please try to read up about any model you use, in this case - logistic regression.

To get probabilities of occurrence of the classes, the input text needs to go under various pre-processing steps in order to provide correct results. One cannot simply use a string to get output from a model.

Please check this [link](https://kavita-ganesan.com/news-classifier-with-logistic-regression-in-python/#.YL4_YvkzaMo) for further info.